# How to get a method to call on another method

Tags: java

I am trying to get the methods to call on each other and produce the bmi calculation. How do I link these methods together so that they print the bmi calculation?

```
public class BodyMassIndex {
    public static String bodyMassIndex(double weight, double height)
    {
        double bmi = weight / (height*height);    
        if (bmi < 16)
        System.out.println("Seriously underweight");
        else if  (bmi >= 16 && bmi < 18)
        System.out.println("Underweight");
        else if (bmi >= 18 && bmi < 24)
        System.out.println("Normal weight");
        else if (bmi >= 24 && bmi < 29)
        System.out.println("Overweight");
        else if (bmi >= 29 && bmi < 35)
        System.out.println("Seriously overweight");
        else if (bmi >= 35 )
        System.out.println("Obese");
        return null; 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double m; 
        double kg;   
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter weight (KG): ");
        kg = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter height (M): ");
        m = input.nextDouble(); 
    }
```

My code is shown above.

Comment: where you are invoking the bodyMassIndex static method?

Comment: I'm not atm - that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BodyMassIndex {
public static void bodyMassIndex(double weight, double height)
{
    double bmi = weight / (height*height);
    if (bmi < 16)
        System.out.println("Seriously underweight");
    else if  (bmi >= 16 && bmi < 18)
        System.out.println("Underweight");
    else if (bmi >= 18 && bmi < 24)
        System.out.println("Normal weight");
    else if (bmi >= 24 && bmi < 29)
        System.out.println("Overweight");
    else if (bmi >= 29 && bmi < 35)
        System.out.println("Seriously overweight");
    else if (bmi >= 35 )
        System.out.println("Obese");


}


public static void main(String[] args){

    double m;
    double kg;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter weight (KG): ");
    kg = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter height (M): ");
    m = input.nextDouble();

    bodyMassIndex(kg, m);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After reading from user **kg** and **m** call the method **bodyMassIndex**

```
System.out.println("Enter weight (KG): ");
kg = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter height (M): ");
m = input.nextDouble(); 

bodyMassIndex(kg, m);
```